# Define right-click area for macbook pro trackpad

Tags: mouse, macbook-pro, touchpad

I'm looking for a way to define the right click area on the trackpad of the macbook pro - the one without a seperate mousebutton.

I'm using the option 'secondary click' where the bottom left (or right) corner works as an area to simulate a right click on a mouse. Unfortunately that ends in too many right-clicks in my workflow, although I'm just clicking 'near' the right/left corner. I want to have this area smaller, that would be awesome. Any ideas how to accomplish this ?

Comment: I thought [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) would get you what you want, but it looks like for trackpads, it will only let you [define actions for taps](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=1619#touchpadgestures) on different areas of the trackpad, not clicks.

Comment: @daxelrod I already had BetterTouchTool, but as I knew that it's not possible to define areas with it, I didn't even try it out. Through your comment I tried it anyway and found out that its pretty much what I wanted, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through a comment left by daxelrod, I tried [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/), which is still not doing what I actually wanted, but at the same time it did!

It's not possible (as far as I know) to define areas for clicking, but when you turn off Macintoshs own right-click/secondary click in the corner and define pretty much the same action in Better Touch Tool, the area will be as small as a thumb right in the edge of the corner - just what I wanted.

Posted as an answer in case someone else is interested in that too. I still wouldn't mind to find out about other ways to do this!