# How do I make the region for right click on the trackpad larger?

Tags: macos, mac, touchpad

Right now I have secondary click set to bottom right corner in system preferences, but I would like for secondary click to be detected on the right half of the track pad. On my pc the trackpad comes built with two equally sized clicking buttons right underneath it. I want to replicate this behavior as close as I can on my mac.

Comment: Just another Apple way how to make your life miserable. Did you found any solution to enlarge the area? Its extremely user unfriendly

Comment: I did not unfortunately. These days I use two-finger tap to right click.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to customize the area.

You may be already aware of this, but I'll just put in the other available options:

- <kbd>Ctri</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> anywhere on the trackpad
- <kbd>Click</kbd> with both fingers anywhere on the trackpad

Both can be configured through System Preferences -> Trackpad. It does take some time getting used to but I find it preferable to frustrating left-clicks because of the small area.

Side note: [This post](https://superuser.com/questions/350164/define-right-click-area-for-macbook-pro-trackpad) has the reverse issue. I haven't researched the mentioned tool, but you may find it useful: [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/)

Comment: thanks for the help, i'll try that out. The guy in the other question must be doing something wrong if he thinks the area is too big by default.